# when click away still triggers Context Menu

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, contextmenu

C# Winform project

I have a dataGridView with a contextMenu. Simply put everything is working as I want it to except it the context menu selection triggers even when I don't want it to (when I click away). 
For instance I right click on my dataGridView I see my selection. If I select it, it triggers a MouseClick event and does what I want. But if I click away it it sill triggers the MouseClick event.

I tried it in a OnMouseUp event in a few different ways but the same is happening. You'll notice a few extra "if's" in the code below which is basically me trying few things to get the MouseClick from triggering unecessarily (althogh in the end I believe it's just doing redundant work).

In code below please note below this: MessageBox.Show("something goes wrong here!");

Code:

```
private void dgvMyDataGridView_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        currentMouseOverCol = dgvMyDataGridView.HitTest(e.X, e.Y).ColumnIndex;
        currentMouseOverRow = dgvMyDataGridView.HitTest(e.X, e.Y).RowIndex;

        ContextMenu m = new ContextMenu();
        if (currentMouseOverRow >= 0 && currentMouseOverCol == 1)
        {
            dgvMyDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString())));
            m.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem(string.Format("Do something with this row")));
        }

        m.Show(dgvMyDataGridView, new Point(e.X, e.Y));
    }

    DataGridView.HitTestInfo hitTestInfo;
    hitTestInfo = dgvMyDataGridView.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);

    if (hitTestInfo.Type == DataGridViewHitTestType.Cell && hitTestInfo.ColumnIndex == 1 && currentMouseOverRow >= 0 && currentMouseOverCol == 1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("something goes wrong here!");
        // Code to open a new form page - this all works.
    }
}
```

What am I missing to tell my application to not trigger when I click away?

Thanks,

~ Chris

Comment: Don't create a context menu this way, create a static context menu and then set `dgvMyDataGridView.ContextMenu = m;`

Comment: @HansZ Would he want it to be static? It's possible (maybe not in his case) that the form can be instantiated multiple times, and then clicking the menu on any of the form would trigger all attached handlers, correct? Wouldn't just a regular member variable of the form be the way to go? Or even set the ContextMenu property for the DataGridView and then re-use that?

Comment: In all honesty I don't remmember why I created it dynamically. I believe it had to do with the realization that I had to create a dynamically built ContextMenu (I have a programmers mind but sorry I'm not as experienced as you guys). In any case I was so close I didn't want to redo everything so I kept at it and believe I fixed my problem. What I needed to do was create an event handler via the contextMenu instead of using the dgvMyDataGridView_MouseClick event. Thanks for your input all.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that your method is continuing to process once the ContextMenu is closed. To fix your solution you just need to `return` after invoking `Show` for your ContextMenu.

Simple fix:

```
m.Show(dgvMyDataGridView, new Point(e.X, e.Y));
return;
```

The problem was that execution of the event handler was still continuing, simply waiting for `m.Show` to "end" when the context menu is closed, similar to the way that `Form.ShowDialog` and `MessageBox.Show` behave.

**UPDATE:** From the comment, it looks like the DataGridView.MouseClick was trying to handle the user clicking on an item of the ContextMenu.  In such a case, you would need to make a larger change to the code, as below:

```
private void dgvMyDataGridView_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        var hitTestInfo = dgvMyDataGridView.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);

        if ((hitTestInfo.Type == DataGridViewHitTestType.Cell) &&
            (hitTestInfo.ColumnIndex == 1) &&
            (hitTestInfo.RowIndex >= 0))
        {
            string currentCell = dgvMyDataGridView.Rows[hitTestInfo.RowIndex].Cells[hitTestInfo.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString();
            ContextMenu m = new ContextMenu();
            dgvMyDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            m.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Click Me!", new EventHandler((itemSender, itemEvent) =>
            {
                var result = MessageBox.Show("You've clicked " + currentCell + ". Open next form?", "Continue?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
                if (result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    // Code to open a new form page.
                }
            })));
            m.Show(dgvMyDataGridView, new Point(e.X, e.Y));
        }
    }
}
```

The key is adding the EventHandler to the MenuItem of your ContextMenu. Hope that helps!

Comment: I believe you're onto something. Strange though, it worked once but for some reason didn't after that. I've been messing with my code all day I could have broken something at some point. I was so close I didn't want to redo everything so I kept at it and believe I fixed my problem. What I needed to do was create an event handler via the contextMenu instead of using the dgvMyDataGridView_MouseClick event. For the record something like this:m.MenuItems.Add("&Do Something ", new EventHandler(EventToCallHere)); Then I setup an event to do what I want it to. I do appreciate your help very much.

Comment: @Chris Ah, so you are saying the second part of your MouseClick handler was the intended result of the ContextMenu? That's a key point, and I'll update my answer to include that fix, for anyone searching a similar problem later.